# What do I put for average value when creating chronicleMap if the value is a class? [Chronicle-Map]

Tags: chronicle-map

I have the following class I want to use as a value for the map I'm implementing:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.BytesMarshallable;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;


public class GlossesLexicalizations implements BytesMarshallable {

    List<String> glosses = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Pair<String, POS.Tag>> lexicalizations = new ArrayList<Pair<String, POS.Tag>>();

    public GlossesLexicalizations(){

    }

    public GlossesLexicalizations(List<String> g, List<Pair<String, POS.Tag>> l){
        glosses = g;
        lexicalizations = l;
    }

    public void setGlosses(List<String> l){
        glosses = l;
    }

    public void setLexicalizations(List<Pair<String, POS.Tag>> l){
        lexicalizations = l;
    }

    public List<String> getGlosses(){
        return glosses;
    }

    public List<Pair<String, POS.Tag>> getLexicalizations(){  
        return lexicalizations;
    }
}
```

I implement `BytesMarshallable` so that ChronicleMap can use it.

Then I create the database:

```
        File file = new File("/home/sandor/Desktop/lexicalizations-and-glosses-map.bin");

        String key = "bn:14232961n"; // example

        List<String> glosses = bn.getGlosses(key, ULocale.US);

        List<Pair<String, POS.Tag>> lexicalizations = bn.getLexicalizations(key, ULocale.US);

        ChronicleMap<String, GlossesLexicalizations> lexicalizationGraph = ChronicleMap
                .of(String.class, GlossesLexicalizations.class)
                .name("lexicalizations-and-glosses")
                .constantKeySizeBySample("bn:14271053n")
                .entries(100) // poner number of entries + 15% extra
                .createOrRecoverPersistedTo(file);

        GlossesLexicalizations gl = new GlossesLexicalizations(glosses, lexicalizations);


        lexicalizationGraph.put(key, gl);

        lexicalizationGraph.close();
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Value size in serialized form must be configured in ChronicleMap, at least approximately. Use builder.averageValue()/.constantValueSizeBySample()/.averageValueSize() methods to configure the size
```

I can understand the average value size for a string, but what do you do for a class?

Answer (score 0):

You can either create an object of your value class `GlossesLexicalizations`, fill it in as you would fill it in real application, and give it as a sample for `averageValue()`, or you can try to guess approximately how much data you will have in your object and use `averageValueSize()` with that number. Don't worry if the number is not exact - it just needs to be in a ballpark. This is required for Chronicle Map to be able to allocate objects in the memory (as you probably know Chronicle Map stores objects in the off-heap memory hence it has to do memory allocations itself).